# Turn output of command into valid json?

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed, jq

How can I use bash commands to convert the output of 'kubectl cluster-info dump' into valid json?

As is, right now, it comes out like this (extremely abbreviated):

```
{
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/nodes",
    "resourceVersion": "24393",
    "Items": [tons of json]
}
{
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/events",
    "resourceVersion": "24393",
    "Items": [tons of json]
}
...
{
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods",
    "resourceVersion": "24393",
    "Items": [tons of json]
}
```

I would like to pipe the output of this command through sed or awk to translate this output into valid json, something like:

```
[{"k","v","k2","v2"},
 {"k","v","k2","v2"},
 ...
 {"k","v","k2","v2"}]
```

which I can then easily parse with json parsers like jq

Comment: So your concern is that you have a list of `{ … }` JSON objects which need to be converted into a JSON array, with `[` before the list, comma separating the objects, and `]` at the end?  There's no need to analyze the material in the objects; those are valid.  But the `Items` section of each object contains copious JSON data.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I'm not as handy with sed and awk as I would like to be but I did finally come up with something, which I'll add below

Comment: It look like your intended output isn't valid JSON either, with the objects being just lists of strings.

Comment: If the layout is as shown, then: `kubectl cluster-info dump | { echo "["; sed -e 's/^}$/},/' -e '$s/^},$/}/'; echo "]"; }` would do the job.  This relies on the "tons of JSON" not having any line containing only `}` in the middle.  Since JSON parsers aren't worried by spaces and newlines, there's no need to do more.

Comment: The default output format of [`kubectl cluster-info dump` is JSON](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-dump-em-); you just have a stream of individual JSON objects rather than a single JSON list. `jq` can handle that easily, per @oguzismail's answer.

Comment: Feel free to close this question, I agree it's too broad and poorly worded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the layout is as shown, then:

```
kubectl cluster-info dump |
{ echo "["; sed -e 's/^}$/},/' -e '$s/^},$/}/'; echo "]"; }
```

would do the job. This relies on the "tons of JSON" not having any line containing only `}` in the middle. Since JSON parsers aren't worried by spaces and newlines, there's no need to do more.

You can avoid the shell `{ …; }` notation with:

```
kubectl cluster-info dump |
sed -e '1s/^/[/' -e 's/^}$/},/' -e '$s/^},$/}]/'
```

The first `sed` commands adds a `[` to the start of the first line; the second changes each line consisting of just `}` to `},` (including the last line), but the third undoes that damage and adds the `]` instead.

You could even combine those `-e` commands into one separated by semicolons.  Personally, I prefer separate `-e` options to make it easer to read.  If they're more complex, I put each one on its own line, with backslash to continue the overall command over multiple lines.

Comment: Do consider the merits of the answer by [oguzismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguzismail).  It uses JQ, which you're planning to do anyway, so it is probably a better solution — even though this answers the direct question of how to do it with `sed` etc.  It's a small case of an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: When I started asking the question, his answer would have worked, but then the output changed and added even more non-json stuff, so I thought it didn't work, but it would have worked if the question as written was the true question.

Comment: So the real answer is something like "kubectl cluster-info dump | sed '/^===/,/===\$/{/^#/!{/^\$/!d;};}' | jq -s"

Answer (score 3):

Pipe your command's output to [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

```
jq -s
```

Comment: Using `jq` (or something similar) is probably best.  When the `...` line is removed and the `[tons of json]` is replaced with `[1, 2, 3]` (which is valid JSON, but not exactly tons of it), then this produces sensible output.

Comment: I wish this would just work, but when I try it I get kubectl cluster-info dump | jq -n '[inputs]'
jq: error (at <stdin>:4215): Invalid numeric literal at line 4215, column 5.  Because the json is not valid

Comment: Can you add line 4215 of the output to your question? `kubectl` is documented to output JSON by default.

Comment: By the way, `jq -s` combines its input into a single list before passing that list to the same filter; `kubectl cluster-info dump | jq -s` should be sufficient.

Comment: Okay, I see, at line 4215, there is some odd stuff where it dumps out some logs in non-json format.  Which makes my whole question sort of invalid. sigh

Comment: It's puzzling that invalid JSON is being produced by `kubectl` when it thinks it is producing JSON output.  Even if the JSON contains log data, that log data should have been sanitized for embedding in JSON, and maybe there's a bug in something that should have converted the data for use in JSON.  Is that added by a plugin of some sort that your organization provided, @slashdottir, or is it all pure Kubernetes and the problem is somewhere in there?

Comment: That is just one of my many many frustrations with kubernetes.

Comment: Answer seems to be: k cluster-info dump | sed '/^===/,/===\$/{/^#/!{/^\$/!d;};}' | jq -s. So technically you are correct based on the wording of the question

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution

```
kubectl cluster-info dump | sed "s/^}$/},/g" | tr '\n' "~" | sed 's/^/[/g' | sed 's/$/]/g' | tr "~" "\n"
```

which produces a json parseable result

Comment: The `tr` commands will do mischief if your data ever contains a tilde.

Comment: Yes, that is true